# how to remove locale dropdown Icon(icon before english word)

Tags: docusaurus

I want to remove the icon in the language dropdown. I just want the text. Is that possible?
[locale dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdJU2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am supposing that you are using the `theme-classic`.

**STEP by STEP:**

0. Open your `Terminal/Power Shell` at the root of your docusaurus.
1. Run the command:

`npm run swizzle @docusaurus/theme-classic IconLanguage -- --danger`

2. Go to the folder `.\src\theme\IconLanguage`
3. Edit the file `index.js`: remove the tag `path` inside the return statement — remove everything from `<path` to `/>`
4. Run your docusaurus

**REFERENCE**

https://docusaurus.io/feature-requests/p/make-the-language-changer-icon-configurable